# Travis does not compile the project

Tags: maven, travis-ci

I have a very simple application, to compile the app in the travis in the `.travis.yml`, i have:

```
git:
  depth: 3
language: java
jdk:
  - oraclejdk8

script: mvn clean install
```

I have tried the command `mvn clean install` in the local machine, and it builds successfully the app, but it fails the travis with the following errors:

```
$ javac -J-Xmx32m -version
javac 1.8.0_31
3.01s$ ./mvnw install -DskipTests=true -Dmaven.javadoc.skip=true -B -V
/home/travis/build.sh: line 218: ./mvnw: Permission denied
The command "eval ./mvnw install -DskipTests=true -Dmaven.javadoc.skip=true -B -V" failed. Retrying, 2 of 3.
/home/travis/build.sh: line 218: ./mvnw: Permission denied
The command "eval ./mvnw install -DskipTests=true -Dmaven.javadoc.skip=true -B -V" failed. Retrying, 3 of 3.
/home/travis/build.sh: line 218: ./mvnw: Permission denied
The command "eval ./mvnw install -DskipTests=true -Dmaven.javadoc.skip=true -B -V" failed 3 times.
The command "./mvnw install -DskipTests=true -Dmaven.javadoc.skip=true -B -V" failed and exited with 126 during .
Your build has been stopped.
```

So, what is wrong?

I use `java spring mvc`

Answer (score 0):

Your travis file is wrong:

```
env:
  - MAVEN_VERSION=3.2.5
  - MAVEN_VERSION=3.3.9
install:
  - "mvn -N io.takari:maven:wrapper -Dmaven=${MAVEN_VERSION}"
  - "./mvnw --show-version --errors --batch-mode test-compile dependency:go-offline"
script: "./mvnw --show-version --errors --batch-mode -Prun-its clean verify"
```

This will run a matrix with two maven versions. If you need only a single one just replace the parameter "${MAVEN_VERSION} with the ony you would like to use....

Furthermore set you cache folder like this:

```
cache:
    directories:
    - $HOME/.m2
```

This will cache also the downloaded maven version and will prevent downloading for each build.

Comment: I tried your code, but it does not work.
https://github.com/salman-/profit-software

Comment: First your pom produces warnings (see in your log) furthermore you seemed to be not able to read the log file, cause at the end you see that you are trying to compile code with Java 8 but on travis you are using JDK 7 which does not work..

Comment: i changed the pom and now it doesn't have warnning. Also, i can read the log, and the error is **Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile **

Answer (score 0):

Try below:

```
git:
  depth: 3
language: java
jdk:
  - oraclejdk8
before_install:
  - chmod +x mvnw
```